# django - one inline for multiple models

Tags: python, django, django-models, inline

I have inline:

```
class GenderInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.GenderModel1
    extra = 0
```

I want to use this inline in different admin forms.

Once I want that his model will be models.GenderModel1, and once models.GenderModel2 (according to the AdminForm this inline is related)

Can I do that? Or the only way is to duplicate the inline? (which I prefer not... I need to duplicate 10 inlines.. ):

```
class GenderInline1(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.GenderModel1
    extra = 0

class GenderInline2(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.GenderModel2
    extra = 0
```

Comment: You can subclass the `admin.StackedInline` to get rid of repeated lines like `extra = 0` but still you have to define 10 inline classes.

Comment: thanks for the fast response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you may create classes on the fly using `type` to avoid defining multipl classes. Define a function that crates an inline like this:

```
def get_inline_by_model(m):
    return type(
        'DynamicInline', 
        (admin.StackedInline, ), 
        {'model':m, 'extra':0} 
    )
```

And then in your Admin class you can just define your inline like:

```
inlines = ( get_inline_by_model (models.GenderModel1 ) ,  )
```